# Cron Job Sends only one email at a time

Tags: php, cron

I have created a php file for cron job. I want To send Lecture details To Users Through this cron job. The code is as follows :

```
 <?
 $login=mysql_query("select * from table1 WHERE member_status = '1'  AND email_lecture_sent ='0' "); 
 $datelogin=mysql_fetch_array($login);

 $current_date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s a");   
 $objTotalRS=mysql_query("select * from  table2 where display_time >'".$current_date."' order by lecture_start asc limit 0,1");


  while ($data=mysql_fetch_array($objTotalRS))  {

        $date1= date("Y-m-d");
        $date2=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($data['lecture_start']));

        $dateDiff = strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1);
        $fullDays = floor($dateDiff/(60*60*24));

          if($datelogin['email_lecture_sent'] = '0'){
    mysql_query(" UPDATE table1 SET email_lecture_sent = '1' WHERE reg_id =".$datelogin['reg_id']);

    }

    if($fullDays=="1" || $fullDays=="2"){
    ob_start(); 
       ?>

         email content containing lecture details along with user's data like username, password etc.. .


 <?
    $body=ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean ();

    $to = $datelogin["email"];
    $sub = "Our Next Live Session";



    $mail->IsHTML(true); 
    $mail->Host = "mail.abc.com";
    $mail->From = "info@abc.com"; 
    $mail->FromName = "ABC"; 

    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    $mail->Subject = $sub;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;
    if($mail->Send()){
    echo"Success...";
    }else{
        echo"oops";
    }


    $mail->ClearAddresses();
    $mail->ClearCCs();
    $mail->ClearBCCs();

        }

     }
         ?>
```

BUT problem is when I run this file, it sends only one email in one cron job and not to all with member_status='1' and email_lecture_sent='0'

Comment: Is your error log showing anything? It could be that it's hitting a fatal error and crapping out

Comment: No there is no error shown in error log

Comment: OT: mysql_query evil -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Maybe if you post the rest of "Email sending php code" we'd be able to check that for faults.

Comment: rest of "Email sending php code" is updated in above question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on above code and redesigned code as follows which worked for me perfectly..

updated code is -

```
<?php
$log= "select * from table1 WHERE member_status = '1' AND email_lecture_sent='0'";
$login=mysql_query($log);

while ($datelogin=mysql_fetch_array($login))  {

    mysql_query(" UPDATE table1 SET email_lecture_sent = '1' WHERE reg_id =".$datelogin['reg_id']);

    $current_date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s a");
    $objTotalRS=mysql_query("select * from  table2 where display_time >'".$current_date."' order by lecture_start asc limit 0,1");

    $data=mysql_fetch_assoc($objTotalRS);

        $date1= date("Y-m-d");
        $date2=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($data['lecture_start']));
        $dateDiff = strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1);
        $fullDays = floor($dateDiff/(60*60*24));


         if ($fullDays=="2" || $fullDays=="1") {
          ob_start();
?>
```

Rest code as above

Thank you for support

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `ob_start();` function in you code.  Bcz if you use `ob_start()` function so it means you again start all objects.

```
if($fullDays=="1" || $fullDays=="2"){
ob_start(); ///// Remove this line.
   ?>
     email contents...
   <?
   rest email sending php code....
   }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Remove only ob_start();  function.